# Как правильно программно подставлять функции в ячейки excel?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

```
                  // ищем номера строк
                  // LastRow = 16
                  // Столбец J8:J16 заполнен
                  for (int j = 8; j <= LastRow; j++)
                  {
                      workSheet.Cells[j, "K"] = "=MATCH(J"+j.ToString()+";A:A;0)";
                  }
```

Такой код должен искать номера строк из столбца `J`, сравнивая со значениями столбца `А` и заполнять столбец `К`.
Но при использовании получаю ошибку:

```
 Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800A0E3C
```

Что, насколько я понял, говорит о неверном диапазоне. Но уже несколько раз перепроверил, вроде всё верно...

Помогите выбраться из логической ямы.

Answer (score 4):

В результате экспериментов и длительного обсуждения все таки нашли проблему.  Но как обычно, сначала искали не там и не то =)

Да, с помощью `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` можно вставлять функции в ячейки и это корректно работает, НО:

1. Имена вызываемых функций должны быть не локализованы, т.е. нужно использовать оригинальные английские имена функций. Сопоставление локализованных и оригинальных имен можно посмотреть, например, **[тут](http://fa-kit.ru/main_dsp.php?top_id=13918)**
2. В русской локали есть особенность: т.к. запятая используется в качестве десятичного разделителя, то в качестве разделителя параметров используется точка с запятой. В оригинальной английской локали десятичный разделитель - точка, и параметры разделяются запятой. В скриптах необходимо использовать вариант для оригинальной английской локали.

Собственно последняя особенность и приводила к ошибке.

По поводу именования ячеек, как оказалось, эксель весьма спокойно относится к указанию адреса столбца буквами, но порядок должен быть обратным, т.е. (строка, столбец).

Пока остался открытым вопрос, о приведении типа значения ячейки к стандартным типам C#.

Comment: а как будет выглядить обращение к J8 в этом случае?

Comment: @p4sh например так `workSheet.Cells[ 7, 8]`

Comment: @p4sh сорри, ошибся немного. тут адреса не x,y как обычно, а y,x, т.е. сначала строка, потом столбец, тогда J8 = (8,7)

Comment: Большое, человечье спасибо

Comment: @p4sh на всякий случай дополню ответ про нумерацию, а то сам периодически забываю =) так напоминалка висеть будет

Comment: если это диапазон A:A, то выглядеть будет так:
   workSheet.Columns["A:A", Type.Missing]

Comment: диапазон задается 2-я ячейками, левого верхнего и правого нижнего углов. И там для этого есть отдельный тип Range кажется

Comment: @p4sh ну можно и так тоже.  Я сильно глубоко не копался, потому как если есть доступ к ячейкам, проще прямо в скрипте делать нужные расчеты и возвращать уже готовые значения в нужные ячейки. Более того, можно использовать функции, не доступные через ячейки самого экселя, например split для текста

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36765/discussion-between-p4sh-and-rdorn).

Comment: Я разрешил вопрос таким образом:

workSheet.Cells[j, "K"] = "=MATCH(J"+j.ToString() +",A:A,0)";