# Числа с запятой при экспорте в Excel

Tags: c#, export

Не получается отображать числа при экспорте в Excel в числовом формате. Сначала все числа экспортировались в текстовом формате. Соответственно при открытии ексель все числа были текстовыми и ексель просил их перевести в числа при желании.

Я написал функцию которая проверяла бы в каком формате числа в БД и если в числовом то так их и оставляла.

Проблема следующая целые числа стали числовыми а вот с запятой так и остались текстовыми хотя при отладке они проверку проходят.

Сама функция:

```
if (objDataType.Contains(TypeCode.Int32.ToString()) || objDataType.Contains(TypeCode.Int64.ToString()) || objDataType.Contains(TypeCode.Decimal.ToString()) || objDataType.Contains(TypeCode.Double.ToString()) || objDataType.Contains(TypeCode.Single.ToString()))
   {
   cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
   cell.CellValue = new CellValue(_table.Rows[i][j].ToString());
   }
   else
   {
   cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
   cell.CellValue = new CellValue(_table.Rows[i][j].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Проверьте региональные настройки. Какой символ стоит как разделитель десятичной части.

Comment: CellValue в качестве аргумента принимает только string.

Comment: И точно запятая приходит.

Comment: А какая библиотека используется для экспорта?

Comment: мой опыт взаимодействия с excell подсказывает, что программно, можно использовать только американский формат, т.е. с точкой "1.0" бодались тут недавно с похожей проблемой, может и вам подойдет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501340/198316

Answer (score 3):

Если проблема с разделителем. Попробуйте так:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "ru-RU", false ).NumberFormat;
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(_table.Rows[i][j].ToString("N", nfi));
```

Инфо: [MSDN NumberDecimalSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Не прокатывает.

Comment: В базе какой разделитель? "." или ","?

Comment: Да проблема была в разделителе. Рекурсивкой просто заменил его и все.Всем спасибо!